# Is Pearson correlation only used for INDIVIDUAL values?

Tags: correlation, interpretation

I believe I read this somewhere, or perhaps I inferred it, but I have never seen it definitely mentioned one way or another.  Should the pairs of data sets come from individual values?  As opposed to mean values.  For example, assume I calculate the high temperature every day for two full years.   I find the MEAN high temperature for each of the 24 months (say, Jan 2020 thru Dec, 2021), and want to do a correlation for twelve pairs of numbers.  (ie Jan 2020 and Jan 2021 is one of the 12 pairs of numbers, etc. thru Dec 2020 and Dec 2021.).  Each of the 24 numbers involved are derived by a MEAN.

On the one hand, I would think that is fine, that a number can come from ANYWHERE (a mean is still an "individual" value).  But its nature is indeed different than a value, such as the high temperature on a given day.  So, does it matter whether those numbers involved are themselves means?

Comment: You can put whatever numbers you want into the equation. How you interpret the result will depend on what you put in, however. What do you want to learn from your data?

Comment: The result will usually be different, because you are averaging out variability at a certain scale. In principle, for each adult still alive who voted in the last election in your country we might know if they have been vaccinated against Covid. In practice, such data are not available, but you might find aggregations at local level (% vote for a party, % vaccinated) and you are even more likely to find aggregations at coarser level (e.g. states and similar in the US). The correlation results will differ,  In reverse the interpretation will differ too.

Comment: thanks for responses. to Daves ?, it would be how predictable machines are year after year, but each value is a mean. I would agree with Nicks response, about averaging out variability, but there is no UNIT to begin with.  meaning, assume one uses individual values for whatever it is, and with a sample size of 30 get a corr value of, .75.  well, it seems that no matter the context, if one gets MEANS as the values, and with the same sample size, gets the same corr .75, it seems to me the interpretation has to be the same because you are measuring STRENGTH of RELATIONSHIP.   is that not correct?

Comment: but therein lies the quandary.  on the one hand, it seems that the interpretation should be the same, but on the other hand because of averaging out variability with MEANS, it seems that while .75 is still a relatively strong relationship, it should mean something slightly different.  does it make sense what I am asking?